# How can I archiving gmail hosted emails on SharePoint Server

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sql-server, incoming-email

I have my email hosted on gmail cloud server, and I am about to get SharePoint 2013. I would like to use SharePoint to archive my gmail email on-premise. Can you advise on what I should do?

Answer (score 1):

the only option I can see is to create a document library with an "email" content type, put the fields you need there

2nd. Create a timer job that reads from GMAIL using their API

Basically your timer job will make web service/rest calls, and once it has the info on memory, then use the sharepoint server API, to create a list item on sharepoint

Seems pretty simple, all you need is to learn their api, info below

Gmail API info here:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/

Comment: Can I do this with SharePoint Designer, Please can I pm you so you can show me how to get around this headache. Plus, will attachment be supported with this option

Comment: This is not a simple thing you will be able to do with SP Designer nor is L.V. likely to be able to help you with it via PM.

Comment: no, you need visual studio and a very good/senior architect developer to do this kind of things.

Answer (score 1):

If you looking for 3rd party solution.

Aspose.Email for SharePoint's email conversion component is an easy-to-use tool for synchronizing emails with SharePoint’s custom list of emails. With support for popular protocols and email servers, like POP3, IMAP and Microsoft Exchange Server, Aspose.Email can connect with a variety of email servers and synchronize email.

This article explains how to set up Gmail so that emails can be downloaded, set up SharePoint to synchronize emails and how to run the synchronization manually.
[Synchronize Emails with Gmail](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/emailsharepoint/Synchronize+Emails+with+Gmail)

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do this using out-of-the-box features.  Your best bet, in my opinion, would be to use a tool like [gmail-backup-com](https://code.google.com/p/gmail-backup-com/wiki/CmdLineUsage) to backup your gmail messages to flat text files, and then bulk load these into a sharepoint document library (using the windows explorer drag and drop would be my approach).

Once they are in a doc library, you can leverage search to work with them.  If you wanted to go with a more advanced approach, you could write some scripts to identify metadata from the message data and use a custom content type for your doc library.

Comment: Hi, is there a way to sync gmail incoming mails to a library in sharepoint. We are looking to deploy sharepoint as an archiving tool however, we still want to use gmail as our mail server. This is a difficult task I know but there should be a way around it

Comment: It's tough to use SharePoint as an email archival tool.  It's difficult to do well out-of-the-box, even if you are using Exchange/Outlook.  Your best bet would be to wire up some automation around the process I described above, and have a scheduled job that runs periodically.  Even if you pull this off, the usability of the email suffers.  It never feels like you are browsing an 'inbox'.  The emails, especially if they are HTML based, will render incorrectly.  Attachments are yet another challenge.